# How to hard reset an Allied Telesis x510?

Tags: switch, hardware

I have a newly opened from the box Allied Telesis Port.

After some configuration, I was locked out due to timed out. I have already setup the Login with correct login and managed to login before.

But now I am locked out. Is there a way to hard reset the Allied Telesis switch again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.alliedtelesis.com/documents/bootloader-and-startup-feature-overview-and-configuration-guide), you can erase the flash and boot from a clean device:

> The next level of security is equivalent to the second one, except
>   that there is no longer any access to the **Skip startup script**
>   option and to the **Special Boot Options** section of the bootloader
>   menu, even of the user knows the password.
>
> Instead, there is a new **completely erase flash** item in the
>   bootloader menu, that now becomes the only option a user has for
>   recovering the switch if the Admin password is lost.